# How should I get return value using "getPlayerState" in youtube player using iframe tag?

Tags: javascript, html, erb

I've given code I used below for pausing the youtube video in iframe which accepts function without parameters and return type. Please let me know how should I get state of player (ended, playing, not started and likewise) using following code:

```
window.frames[playerName].postMessage(JSON.stringify({
              "event": "command",
              "func": function,
              "args": 0,
              "id": 1 /*Can be omitted.*/
        }), "*");
```